# Mutiprocessing hanging issue

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I am using multiprocessing. My CPU has four cores and I set the pool's processes=2.

1) If I run the same program concurrently (multiple run same times) it will use all my cores? I yes, how to setup one cores always free if it is running concurrently.

2) I run individually for each country there is no issue but If I run the above file concurrently with different country it hangs after 7-8 hours

Any idea about why it is hanging and how to trace the reason for hanging?

```
import  time
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial
import os

class Test:
    country = ''

    def __init__(self, countryCode):
        self.country = countryCode

    def Mainfn_New(self):
        #around 10-20 files
        inputpath = "C:\\" + self.country + "\\Inputfiles"
        dirlist = os.listdir(inputpath)
        print(inputpath)
        print(dirlist)
        print("START Main")

        pool = Pool(2)
        func = partial(self.HugeProcess, inputpath)
        results = pool.map(func, dirlist)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        print("End Main")

    def HugeProcess(self, inputpath, filename):
        #Proces will take around 10-30 mins to complete the process
        print("START HugeProcess ***" , filename)
        #time.sleep(1)
        print("END HugeProcess ***", filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Starting .........")
    #country code MY
    obj = Test('MY')
    obj.Mainfn_New()
```

Comment: Your code requires 3 cores to run (although one of them is just the main process which spends most of its time waiting — so if you have 4 and you want to keep one core free, then you shouldn't run it concurrently. I think a better design would be to make a `dirlist` of all the files for all the countries, and process all of them with a `Pool`. Since the main thread does very little, I think you could make the `Pool` size 3 instead of 2.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually cores I given as an example to explain I want to free once core always. This program is using for different countries and it depends on user to submit the jobs when he wants. I tested with concurrent run cause the issue bcos concurrent run could be possible in my case. I noticed on putty that the jobs are running but after 6-7 hours thread went to sleeping mode. Is is because system is taking all the cores?

Comment: No, using all the cores at once would not put a system to sleep.